# chart.js - user add the final point of the line

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

i need to make a line chart where the user complete the last point on the chart then take an action depending on it.
i'm using Chart.js but if that is supported in any library i'm open to change.
so any ideas?
thanks

Comment: It's possible to update the chart with new data. You can easily get that data from the user through an input box or something... Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no.. what i need is to let him draw the line from the last point to the new one (drag it or something)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot draw a line using chart.js the best solution would be a shift to D3 charts where you can make custom charts lines etc..

**You can create a line using D3 as below**

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);


var circle = svgContainer.append("line")
    .attr("x1", 5)
    .attr("y1", 5)
    .attr("x2", 50)
    .attr("y2", 50)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Comment: but how the user will edit that?
here is an example of what i need to do: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/01/15/us/politics/you-draw-obama-legacy.html
but i cannot figure out what used in it